# Почему не обновляется статистика в Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play

Почему не обновляется статистика в Google Play Developer Console?
Опубликовал приложение 29 октября.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Постоянные задержки с обновлением данных - норма. Задержки бывают вплоть до нескольких дней. Единственное, что остаётся - ждать.

Comment: спасибо Юрий вы меня уже не в первые выручаете))) Спасибо большое)))